# DB2 Connect Fails with correct username / password

Tags: linux, db2

This is the list of commands I am running... which will explain my problem...

```
$ su user
Password:
[user@localhost]$ db2 list database directory

System Database Directory
Number of entries in the directory = 1
Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = MYDB
 Database name                        = MYDB
 Local database directory             = /scratch/db2inst2
 Database release level               = f.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =


[user@localhost]$ db2 connect to MYDB
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

I am not sure why this is happening.. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does your password end in `!` ?

Comment: Are you actually able to login to the database server (using ssh or similar) using the user ID and password?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde Yes... thats why I posed the bash results... I can su to my user... but can't connect to DB

Comment: Please provide the full output from `list database directory` for the database in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the user you are trying to connect to the database.

- The user has not the necessary rights to connect to the database.
- You did a su user, but the environment has not changed completely. Make sure which user is used to connect to the database, the current instance $DB2INSTANCE.
- You have updated DB2, but the instance has not been updated db2iupdt.
- Try to connect to the database by specifying all parameters

For example

```
 db2 connect to MYDB user user using mypasswd
```

For more information about your error consult the infocenter about SQL30082

```
db2 ? sql30082
```

Reason 24